# Automated method to figure out whether a recognition site is conserved or not using the results of simulated restriction digestion

Tags: sequence-alignment, 16rrna, emboss

> Restrict from EMBOSS Suit version 6.3.1 with the following
> parameters: snucleotide1, sitelen = 4, rformat = table, enzymes =
> enzymes.txt.
> From the 4379 enzymes present in REBASE, we selected the 650 restriction enzymes that were commercially available, since this assay is meant to be used in any laboratory. From the 650 enzymes, 152 digest all P. salmonis sequences and only 65 recognized conserved restriction sites in the complete set of sequences, generating the same/similar restriction pattern (same number of bands and similar sizes).

https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fmicb.2016.00643/full

If my reading is correct, these researchers figured out the conservation of the restriction sites from the resulting virtual patterns.

The coordinates of a cut can be different in two related sequences even if the restriction site is conserved. This is because base insertions/deletions could occur before/after the restriction site.

**How do i figure out if a recognition sequence is conserved or not, if the coordinates of the cut are not the same in the sequences? How do i automate this?**

We can consider this as an example:

I have two sequences of the 16s rRNA gene from two strains of a bacterial species. When i run EMBOSS's restrict by the following command:

> restrict -sitelen 4 -enzymes HaeIII -snucleotide_sequence 1 -sequence
> sequences.fasta -rformat excel -fragments true -outfile patterns.xls

[Sequences link](https://pastebin.com/0ua0dw30)

The result is:

[image]